# Does unhandled exception before Page_Unload stop Page_Unload handler from running?

Tags: asp.net

Does ASP.NET execute the Page_Unload handler regardless of an unhandled exception during page execution, or do you have to manually catch exceptions in page code blocks to be sure that Unload will always run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an unhandled exception occurs, the only event that is triggered is Application_OnError, no more page events are triggered. If you want the page cycle to contine you have to catch the exception.

Comment: Does Page_Error run before Application_Error though?

Comment: @Sam: Yes, I even think that the Page object is disposed before the Application_Error is called.

Comment: This is wrong. Page_Unload runs even if an exception occurs -- I know because I found this page in hopes of dealing with a side effect of this unexpected behavior.

Comment: (although: it may have been true back in 2009 when this was answered).

Answer (score 2):

This is just for posterity, since I was searching for this answer and found this page fairly early on.

Tests on an ASP.Net 2.0 website I'm running and the article here:

http://forums.asp.net/t/515267.aspx/1?Is+Page_Unload+always+called+

Seem to indicate that Page_Unload() is always called.  (Whether interrupted by Redirect, Transfer, or Exception)